# When connecting PowerBI to Azure Data lake storage v2 ( adls v2 ) ; it gives error 404 "The specified container does not exist"

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-data-lake-gen2

When connecting PowerBI desktop to Azure Data lake storage v2 ( adls v2 ) ; it gives error 404 "The specified container does not exist". Even though container do exist.

Answer (score 1):

I spent few days on this. Even tried Microsoft Support Request but that was also not helpful. I made sure of following but still it was not working:

1. Use dfs URL and NOT blob URL. Include container name in the URL. ex. `https://StorageAccountName.dfs.core.windows.net/ContainerName`
2. Azure Documentation  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/datalakestorage that Drivers.txt should also be available in the container. Not sure if this is really required.
3. Account should be Hierarchial namespace enabled.

Real problem was that of "Access issue". Azure is really not good at giving right "error message".  Worst part is that there are multiple level of access and even if one is not correct, you are stuck.   More importantly:

1. Make sure that Storage account has your IP Address access too.
2. You have "Storage account" level permissions and not at container level.